# How to programmatically log in to microsoft online?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, azure

In my code (C# MVC App) I have access to a password and username. I want to create a Microsoft online cookie for the user, so he can access an application without providing his credentials again (SSO).

How can I programmatically sign in a user to microsoft online?

Comment: That question is over 5 years old, works with non-existing links and doesn't has a solution....

Comment: maybe use Azure App Service? https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/app-service-mobile-how-to-configure-microsoft-authentication/